# Объясните пожалуйста почему null?

Tags: javascript

Извините, если вопрос глупый, но почему в данном случае в переменной x лежит null:

```js
var x = 2 && 1 && null && 0 && undefined;

console.log(x);
```

в этом единица:

```js
var x = 2 && 1;

console.log(x);
```

а в этом 2:

```js
var x = 1 && 2;

console.log(x);
```

А тут 3:

```js
console.log(null || 2 && 3 || 4);
```

Comment: Побитовые операции (операторы) не при чем, `&&` и `||` - это операторы **[логические](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Логические_операторы)**

Comment: @yar85, поторопился ваша правда.

Comment: [ECMAScript 5.1 / Бинарные логические операторы](https://es5.javascript.ru/x11.html#x11.11) Lyy, а вы про спецификацию не знали, знали, но не читали или читали, но не поняли? Вопрос без подвоха.

Comment: Куда проще иметь дело с визуально понятной и доступной новичку информацией.Ответ выше более чем исчерпывающий, а информация по ссылке, которую вы указали совершенно нечитабельна и непонятна(лично мне).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не сочтите за труд уточнить знали ли вы до сего дня о наличии стандарта ecma-262 (на пятую редакцию которого я ссылаюсь в предыдущем комментарии).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я не силен в js, но скорее всего тут все так же как и в других языках. Логические операторы выполняются по такому принципу, что если результат известен по одному операнду, то второй не вычисляется.

Логическое **И** `&&` вернет первый операнд, если он при приведении к логическому типу дает `false`, причем дальше вычисление не производится, то есть `a() && b()` не будет вычислять `b()`, если `a` вернуло то, что привелось к `false`. Иначе вернет второй операнд.

Логическое **ИЛИ** `||` - наоборот, возвращает первый операнд, если он истинный.

---

#### Пример с &&

```
var x = 2 && 1 && null && 0 && undefined;
```

`2` приведется к `true`

```
var x = 1 && null && 0 && undefined;
```

`1` тоже

```
var x = null && 0 && undefined;
```

а вот `null` приведется к `false`, поэтому дальше ничего не вычисляем.

---

#### Пример с ||

Пример с `||` вернет 1, потому что это первый попавшийся "истинный" операнд.

```js
var x = null || 0 || undefined || 1 || true || false;
console.log(x);
```

---

#### Пример с обоими операторами.

Приоритет оператора `&&` выше, чем у `||`. Значит, выражение

```
null || 2 && 3 || 4
```

будет посчитано как

```
null || (2 && 3) || 4
```

`null` приводится к `false`, поэтому получаем

```
(2 && 3) || 4
```

в скобках будет `3`

```
3 || 4
```

и получаем `3`.

Выражение в скобках не вычислялось бы, если бы первый аргумент был бы истинным:

```js
console.log(true || 2 && 3 || 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let x = 1 && 2
```

Смысл в том, что если первое значение верно, то присвоит второе, если же одним из условий будет `null`, то и вернёт `null` в переменную. Концепция думаю понятна.

Если

```
let x = 3 || 4
```

Парсер выбирает то, что первым будет true, то есть 
 `3 === true`
Вот он его и выбрал, если будет `let x = 0 || 4` , то x будет равен 4.